# Mask Image to Video Frame similar as MV Master

Tags: ffmpeg, android, video-editing

I am new to this video processing concept, i tried to use the video sample downloaded from the [link](http://ak-mv.inscoming.com/zif/2019/01/04/14/027ac097fb788c698ad5e7cb3c92fd69.zip) of MV Master. And used ffmpeg to mask images in the video same as MV Master does in their app. I used VideoKit([link](https://github.com/inFullMobile/videokit-ffmpeg-android)) to do that. Can any one help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

i read all comments and got that ur looking for ffmpeg command that get 2 to 3 images a input and one alpha rgb video for effect which is used by MV Master app i have made ffmpeg command using ffmpeg documentation and got desired out put as MV Master App Do. cheack out below out put and let me know if your are looking for same will share code if u need

https://www25.zippyshare.com/v/JCMwOZnB/file.html

actually video you got from MV Master app is RGB + ALPHA Video which is used to create MV video effects. you got both video in one video . both video has black color so by using ffmpeg we have to pass black color code to ffmpeg command. ffmpeg will use that black color as transperent area and after that we have to overlay that video to image